# Existence of solutions to linear evolution equation with a noncoercive operator

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, bochner-spaces

Consider the Gelfand triple $V\hookrightarrow H \hookrightarrow V'$ and, for given $T>0$, the Sobolev-Bochner space
$$
\mathcal W(0,T) := \{ v \in L^2(0,T;V): \dot v \in L^2(0,T;V')\}.
$$

Consider the linear and bounded operator $A\colon V \to V'$, consider $f\in L^2(0,T;V')$, an initial value $\alpha \in H$, and the linear evolution problem:

\begin{align}
\dot v(t) + Av(t) &= f(t), \tag{*}\\
v(0) &= \alpha.
\end{align}

By means of a Galerkin scheme, one can prove that $(*)$ has a unique solution $v \in \mathcal W(0,T)$, provided $A$ is positive or coercive, i.e. $\langle Au, u\rangle \geq c \|u\|^2$ for all $u\in V$, see, e.g., Ch. 23.9, in the book *Nonlinear Functional Analysis, 2A* by Zeidler.

Where can I find results on $(*)$ that do not require (strict) positivity of $A$ (but maybe only $\langle Av, v\rangle \geq 0$), trading in the uniqueness of the solutions?

Answer (score 0):

A natural assumptions is a weaker form of coercivity still - something like: There exists $\alpha,\beta > 0$ such that
$$
   \langle A v, v \rangle \ge \alpha \| v \|_V - \beta \| v \|_H  \quad \mbox{ for all } v \in V
$$

This allows a formal energy estimate like
$$
  \frac{1}{2} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \left( \| u \|_H^2 \right) + \alpha \| u \|_V^2 \le c \left( \| u \|_H^2 + \| f \|_H^2 \right).
$$

This estimate with a Grönwall inequality allows both existence and uniqueness of solutions.

The arguments in Section 7.1 of Evans' *Partial Differential Equations* basically cover this case.

With some work this should be transferable to the case $\langle A v, v \rangle \ge 0$ (i.e. $\alpha = \beta = 0$).